# How do I call a javascript function in addition to a server-side callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have some markup like this:

```
<form id="ddlSelections" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DDL3" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL3" OnSelectedIndexChanged="testFunc" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>

<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

When the drop down list `DDL3` changes, a callback to `testFunc` is performed. I want to add an additional event handler to this drop down box that will update `placeholder` div. For this I am trying to use `jQuery`. I tried this in the head tag:

```
$(function () {
       $("#DDL3").click(function () {
           alert("Clicked" + $("#DDL3").val());
       });
});
```

but jQuery is not catching these events. I am guessing this is because ASP is perhaps over-writing the event handlers.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

**EDIT: What gets rendered:**

```
<select id="DDL3" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'DDL3\',\'\')', 0)" name="DDL3">
```

Comment: `$("#DDL3").change() {}` is not valid JavaScript. Could you post some concrete tries?

Comment: Sorry! Updated with the actual code.

Comment: For reference, you don't need (or want, really) `javascript:` in event handlers.  It "works" because it's parsed as a label, but it has no purpose.  `javascript:` is a URL scheme, and is only useful in link targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "*issue*" is the `<asp:UpdatePanel>`. UpdatePanels rewrite their contents when they update, so the `<select>` you're binding to probably isn't the `<select>` you're interacting with -- even if they look the same.

You can listen to Microsoft Ajax' events -- either [`endRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx) or [`pageLoaded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397523.aspx) -- after which you can bind as you were:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function () {
    $('#<%= DDL3.ClientID %>').click(function () {
        alert("Clicked " + $(this).val();
    });
});
```

Or, use jQuery's [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$('#<%= DDL3.ClientID %>').live('click', function () {
    alert("Clicked " + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: +1 Ok the `live` one worked! I will accept this as an answer because it does not require any ASP specific hacks and also the explanation was very helpful to me. Thank you!

Comment: @Legend: If you put the DropDownList inside of a control that implements `INamingContainer`, this will not work. You'll need to use the `ClientID`, which is why I suggested it. The `ClientID` approach will work regardless of where in the page the control is located.

Comment: @JamesJohnson [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx), if available, can counter that, but of course `ClientID` is far less error-prone. Was just nice to see someone not *yet* have to use it, so I left it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since it's an ASP.NET control, you need to reference it by the `ClientID`:

Here is the test case:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnl" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL3" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Test" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Test 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>                    
    </ContentTemplate>                
</asp:UpdatePanel>                
<div id="placeholder">I'm here</div>
```

There are two ways to handle the selection change:

```
$(function() {
    $("#<%=DDL3.ClientID%>").change(function(e) {
        $("#placeholder").html("Hello world!");
    });
});
```

You can use this approach too if you prefer:

```
$(function() {
    $("#<%=DDL3.ClientID%> option").click(function() {
        $("#placeholder").html("Hello world!");
    });
});
```

If neither of the above work, another solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974606/jquery-event-handler-inside-updatepanel-not-working-after-postback).

Comment: Thank You. It still does not work. When I checked the HTML source of the rendered page, it still substitutes the ID I was using. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean that it's still using `DDL3` instead of the full ID?

Comment: Yes. Also, I updated my question with what is getting rendered after incorporating your suggestion.

Comment: Are you setting `ClientIDMode` to `Static` anywhere?

Comment: Actually no. I did not modify that setting. I am currently looking into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels Maybe it has something to do with my situation. I will try this in the mean time.

Comment: See edited answer. Tested it myself, and it works. I was missing the argument `(e)`

Comment: +1 for your time. Sorry! It does not seem to work for me but thank you for all the suggestions. I added a link to the solution that did work for me. It looks like an UpdatePanel updates everything so we need to add the event handlers every time an update is performed.

Comment: I tested it with an update panel... that's very strange that it didn't work for you.

Comment: I am not sure if something else is conflicting with it. It could very well be a mistake on my side. I will revisit this one. However, the link I posted as well the procedure outlined in the other post worked well for me.